# How to choose the text use in a cross-reference with Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, cross-reference

Using sphinx, I included a figure using the following syntax.

```
.. _struct_NiO:

.. figure:: img/NiO.png
   :align: center
   :width: 400px

   long long very long caption ...
```

In another part of the text I used

```
See figure :ref:`struct_NiO` bla bla bla
```

in order to do a cross reference to the figure. This work, but the output looks like :

See figure "long long very long caption ..." bla bla bla.

This is the normal behavior of sphinx, but if you have a figure a little bit complicated with a 3 or 4 lines caption it is no really adapted.

Is it possible to select the text used in the cross reference ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can provide a custom link text for `:ref:` targets, like this:

```
See figure :ref:`Link text <struct_NiO>` bla bla bla
```

See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role.